# Multiple tag pools for a document type

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We have a document base that needs the metadata to be structured in order to facilitate search, but due to the nature of the information, it will be impossible to use constraints. Tagging seems like an interesting option: it keeps the metadata structured, but allows users to create new values on the fly.

The problem with this solution is that each property needs to have a specific pool of tags. Imagine a document with two properties:

- Entity
- Process

In theory, we could put this information into metadata fields with constraints (database backed even), but the users want to be able to create values on the fly. Tags seem interesting, but we don't want to mix tags from the Entity list with tags from the Process list. Each tag should have its own "pool".

Has anyone done something like this in Alfresco? It seems like we'd have to tear apart the tagging system and basically rewrite it, but maybe it's easier than that.

Answer (score 2):

If your only issue with tag is related to on the fly creation then you should look into "Categories". In Categories only admin user can create required Category structure.Then normal user will be able to use them to categories docs.

I your case I guess you require something like this

- Entity

  - Entity1
  - Entity2
  - Entity3
    ....
- Process

  - Process1
  - Process2
  - Process3
    .....

If yes, you should b able to use categories.

Comment: I've looked into using categories. We would need to be able to specify the base of the category, but the component (ftl) only takes a hard coded noderef to specify the start node. Also, you can't create them on the fly, only the administrator can. So it looks like we're looking at heavy development, either using database tables or the category tree as the backing...